# How do I run tensorflow profiling in tensorflow 2.5

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I am running python 3.85 with Anaconda on Big Sur 11.5

```
% conda list tensor
# packages in environment at /Users/davidlaxer/anaconda3/envs/ai:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
tensor2tensor             1.15.7                   pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard               2.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard-data-server   0.6.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard-plugin-profile 2.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard-plugin-wit    1.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow                2.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-datasets       4.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-estimator      2.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-hub            0.12.0                   pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-metadata       1.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-probability    0.13.0rc0                pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-text           2.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
```

Here's test code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from utils import *
from VDSH import *

tf.compat.v1.enable_v2_behavior()
from tensorflow.python.framework.ops import disable_eager_execution
disable_eager_execution()

#gpu_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
#tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu_devices[0], True)
options = tf.profiler.experimental.ProfilerOptions(host_tracer_level = 3,
                                                   python_tracer_level = 1,
                                                   device_tracer_level = 1)
tf.profiler.experimental.start('~/logdir', options=options)
...
tf.profiler.experimental.stop()
```

Here's the error message:

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.compat.v1.profiler' has no attribute 'experimental'

Comment: Why are you enabled `v2_behaviour`? In Tensorflow 2.x, eager execution enabled by default.

Comment: Why are again disabling eager execution? Can you try above code without `tf.compat.v1.enable_v2_behavior() from tensorflow.python.framework.ops import disable_eager_execution disable_eager_execution()` and let us know?

Comment: File "/Users/davidlaxer/VariationalDeepSemanticHashing/test.py", line 14, in <module>
    options = tf.profiler.experimental.ProfilerOptions(host_tracer_level = 3,
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.compat.v1.profiler' has no attribute 'experimental'

Answer (score 0):

To display the Profile tab in tensorboard requires Chrome.